# Close button on question page on mobile version of SO has recently stopped functioning

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web

I'm using mobile version of stackoverflow.com every now and then and have been able to spot a problem that close button on question page is not functioning: close dialog doesn't open.

The problem has been reproduced in the latest versions of Chrome mobile and Opera Mini browsers on iPhone 4G. The problem might be connected with the recent update of close dialog functionality, as it had been working before that update. Switching to 'full site version' yields correct functionality.

Technically, the close button sends a redirect with a hash sign appended to the current URL with no subsequent action undertaken. Probably there might be an error in the JavaScript engine used on SO.

Any clues on such behaviour?

Comment: Heh, I'm on my mobile, and can't VtC... How ironic.

Comment: @Matt You can always switch to full site mode, you know it :) But still, closing this question as a question having an answer in an unanswered question is, err, kind of tautology.